# Mirror Shapes in SVG more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, svg

This is probably a rather simple problem but I have no idea how to fix it.
Im using C# and WPF and im drawing Shapes in a Canvas. So far so good.
After I drew them I want to save them as a SVG file, which is also no big deal an is working fine.

However, I want to generate a pattern by mirroring this single shape for example 5 times.
Heres a picture to clarify how it should look like:
[image]

Now my question is, how do I do this, meaning how to do this using SVG.
It would be rather stupid to just write transform="scale(-1,1) scale(-1,1)" etc.. 5 times, or is this the only way?

And the 2.Question would be, how do I calculate the mirrored points in C#?

Comment: You must know how big your triangles are, so it should be easy to calculate your positions/transforms.  Note that you can design your pattern shape once, and reuse it using the `<use>` element.

Comment: The problem is im not only using triangles. I want to use any sort of shape and mirror those as one tile. So could I group all of my single shapes in a tile using <symbol> and the scale it -1 by using <use>?

Comment: Yes. That would be a reasonable approach.

Comment: Well thank you very much, this approach worked perfectly.